# Do barcode scanner and signature capture need licence in Rhomobile Suite?

Tags: rhomobile

Do barcode scanner and signature capture need licence in Rhomobile Suite?

Can coding be done for barcode scanner and signature capture in free version of Rhomobile Suite?

Please, somebody respond quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Rhodes version `3.3.3` those device capabilities require a licence. You can however use an older version of Rhodes where those device capabilities are available without a licence. This is explained [here in the documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps)

Comment: I am using MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13. This means that I can code for barcode scanner and signature capture using MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.2.1.13.

Comment: My response was meant to offer an alternative that wouldn't require a licence. Rhodes is also one of RhoMobile's products which should be possible to download from GitHub or as a Ruby Gem. If you use RhoMobileSuite (RhoElements) the following page explains which features require licence and how to obtain one: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/licensing

Answer (score 0):

If you go for Rhoelements then you have to buy the licence ,Regarding Signature you can go for JQuery like Sketch and JQuery signature ,I am using  Barcode as Rhoelemnts, I dont know whether alternate option will be there for Barcode.